# Android - Is there a way to bypass the need to request user permission for gps?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gps

I am developing single `application` mode in android, in which there is no need to request for user's approval.

It even can be done as Native application (ndk) on root device.
But still, I am not sure if there is a way to handle it with `GPS` `permissions`.

It seems not to be enough to declare permissions in `manifest` file.

Is there a way to do it without asking user's `permission` ?

Comment: There wouldn't be much use in having permissions if they could be bypassed.

Comment: right... I understand that. But in case of single application there is much logic in that.

Comment: you don't need to ask user about permission in run-time when you are targeting API older than 22 (of course permission then will be "asked" during installation and still need to be present in Manifest). but then user runing 6.0 can remove that permission from app and you will not known about it

Answer (score 5):

> I am developing single application mode in android, in which there is no need to request for user's approval.

For privacy reasons system thinks otherwise and unless you build your own system, root your device (and plant some patches) or (perhaps) sign your app with system certificate you are not able to prevent system from asking for user consent prior granting you GPS access.